# C++ template class and return type as a constraint

Tags: c++, templates, return-type

Sorry for this foolish question, but I'm quite new to C++.

I have a base class called `AlertInfoBase` in my project. It has some dozens of subclasses. Now I want to have a class template, which will have a method `filter()`. This method will always return a reference to `AlertInfoBase`. Here's the code:

```
template <class T>
class AlertInfoFilter
{
public:
    AlertInfoFilter() { }
    AlertInfoBase & filter(T & alertInfo)
    {
        return alertInfo;
    }
};
```

As you can see, the method filter just returns the passed parameter. My goal is to create alternate implementations of `filter()` using template specialization, but this is not my problem/question right now.
The strange thing I'm facing is that, when I pass an instance of a class to `filter()`, which is subclassed from `AlertInfoBase`, everything works as expected. It returns same reference, but when I pass an instance of a class which doesn't implement `AlertInfoBase`, the project doesn't compile. Actually this is the kind of behavior I want to have, but some clarification why is this happening would be nice. Is the compiler smart enough to guess that I fill the method with incorrect parameter due to return type?

Thanks

P.S. I'm using MinGW compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of templates as a code generation mechanism. A particular instantiation of a template is identical in most ways to manually written code that just substituted the template argument where appropriate. In your example, if you instantiated `AlertInfoFilter` with a `std::string` (as an example of a class that does not inherit from AlertInfoBase), then the following code would be generated (approximately):

```
class AlertInfoFilter_string
{
public:
    AlertInfoFilter_string() { }
    AlertInfoBase & filter(std::string & alertInfo)
    {
        return alertInfo;
    }
};
```

Clearly, this should not compile.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the compiler is exactly smart enough to know that. It's using the implicit conversion from child to base class when T descends from `AlertInfoBase` and isn't able to convert your `T` to the return type in other cases.

It would also work with a class that implemented `operator AlertInfoBase&` in an unrelated class but that would just add confusion so I don't suggest it.

Comment: I would be very interested how you'd implement that operator :) I can think of contrived ways, but unless the type `is-a` or `has-a` AlertInfoBase there wouldn't seem to be a natural fit :) (note that this was what I hinting at with 'convertible to' instead of 'derived from' in my answer)

Comment: It would also work for shims that share a single `AlertInfoBase`.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` takes a `T` as input and converts it to an `AlertInfoBase`. If `T` is now a type that is not a sub-class of `AlertInfoBase`, and does not offer a conversion, then the program cannot be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the compiler does something ver close to taking the code, substituting T for the actual argument and compiling the template. This happens once for every different T you use in your program.

When you pass eg. an `int`, you get:

```
class AlertInfoFilter
{
public:
    AlertInfoFilter() { }
    AlertInfoBase & filter(int & alertInfo)
    {
        return alertInfo;
    }
};
```

which obviously doesn't compile.